# Is there a common wire color for PGD and PGC?

Tags: pic, integrated-circuit, colour-coding

Is there a common color for micro controller programming data and clock wires?

Comment: No there is no commonly agreed-upon color coding. If you want to do something logical, don't use black or red which are usually power- or maybe green which is often ground. You *could* use green and blue which might sort-of make sense for pins 5 and 4 on the Microchip connector scheme.

Comment: And if you have a wire that is bi-color I would take that one for the clock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.